# how to simplify and make it better using enum, swift learning, enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, xcode7

I am defining some of ranges by following

```
let range0_15   =   0 ..< 15
let range15_30  =   15 ..< 30
let range30_45  =   30 ..< 45
let range45_60  =   45 ..< 60
```

I really want to use `Enum` for this by trying

```
enum range : Range<Int> {
    range0_15   =   0 ..< 15
    range15_30  =   15 ..< 30
    range30_45  =   30 ..< 45
    range45_60  =   45 ..< 60
}
```

And I am getting an error

```
Type 'CoreDataStach.range' does not comform to protocol RawRepresentable
```

Is it possible to define an enum like above and if it is yes, what I am missing right here.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
enum rangeEnum : Int {
    case range0_15
    case range15_30
    case range30_45
    case range45_60
    
    var range:Range<Int> {
        switch self {
        case .range0_15 : return 0 ..< 15
        case .range15_30 : return 15 ..< 30
        case .range30_45 : return 30 ..< 45
        case .range45_60 : return 45 ..< 60
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use

```
rangeEnumVariable.range
```

or:

```
rangeEnum.range0_15.range
```

Comment: can you explain. Im totally lost. Why we need to do `case range0_15` and then `var range:Range<Int>`

Comment: He's defining the enum, then using a Switch statement so that you can access the ranges that you've defined to set other variables or use in other logic statements. Personally I would just use a struct for this kind of thing.

Comment: The first case statements define the enum. By saying case range0_15 we are declaring that range0_15 is a case of the rangeEnum. This way, when we want our range, we check which case the object is and return the corresponding value. The var range:Range<Int> is simply a variable of the rangeEnum; we are just stating what to return when we ask for that variable

Comment: Each enumeration definition defines a brand new type. Like other types in Swift, their names (such as CompassPoint and Planet) should start with a capital letter. Give enumeration types singular rather than plural names, so that they read as self-evident:

Comment: Yes, this is correct. This should be RangeEnum and Range0_15 etc. However, I did it this way in an effort to make it easier for tonytran to follow and see the comparisons to his attempt. I probably should not have sacrificed good practice in this case or should have at least addressed it in my answer

Answer (score 4):

You might be better off trying something like this using a struct.

```
struct Ranges{
    static let range0_15   =   0 ..< 15
    static let range15_30  =   15 ..< 30
    static let range30_45  =   30 ..< 45
    static let range45_60  =   45 ..< 60
}

if Ranges.range0_15.contains(6){ //Test to true
    print("inside range")//Prints "inside range"
}
```

Comment: should be `struct Ranges` capital R

Comment: Give types UpperCamelCase names (such as SomeClass and SomeStructure here) to match the capitalization of standard Swift types (such as String, Int, and Bool)